# Jquery UI global tooltip unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui

I have a template system for creating PHP pages.  In my template's jquery document ready function I have the following code to set up a 'global' tooltip for all elements that would usually show a browser default tooltip ...

```
$( document ).tooltip({ classes: { "ui-tooltip": "ui-corner-all my-ui-widget-shadow" }});
```

But it behaves oddly.  For instance, sometimes it appears when I haven't hovered over something.  In the example screenshot below, when I click the button on the modal dialog I have it generate another dialog.  The tooltip for that dialog's close button appears when I haven't hovered over the close button,  and stays until I click...

[image]

And the tooltip will persist in some areas when I've moved the mouse cursor away.  In the example below I hovered over this row, the tooltip appears (correctly) then I click a button over on the right end of the row, which shows a modal form.  When I close that modal form the tooltip remains visible until I click somewhere.

[image: tooltip gets stuck]

Is there a better, 'best-practices' way to replace the browser's default tooltip with the JqueryUI tooltip without resulting in this behaviour?

Comment: Not sure, but try to set tooltip to a selector instead of document.

Comment: You mean a specific class or ID?  How would I do that without having to add that class or id to every single element on my page/template?

Comment: Never tried adding tooltip to document, so really no idea if it helps
`$('body *');`
That will also return script tags.